# New Features not snappable

Tags: qgis, python, snapping

I wrote some Tools for CAD in QGIS with python. Therefore I add a special temporary layer with python, if this layer does not exist. That works fine. To add a new feature I start edit, add the feature, end edit and commit. The feature appears and is added. I can identify it and snap it. That works fine too. But then I cannot snap to every further feature I add to the same layer with the same code, until I open the project again. All these features are visible and can be identified. Only snapping fails. 
I think it could have to do with the feature ID,  but I have no idea what to do.
Snapping is activated for all layers, before I start the plugin.

The code to create the layer:

```
def createMeasurePointLayer(iface, LayerName):
prCRS=iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs().authid()
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + prCRS, LayerName, "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
vl.startEditing()
pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField("fid", QVariant.Int),
                    QgsField("Punktnummer", QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("Foto", QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("geändert von", QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("geändert am", QVariant.DateTime),
                    QgsField("erstellt von", QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("erstellt am", QVariant.DateTime),
                    QgsField("erstellt durch Methode", QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("geändert durch Methode", QVariant.String)])
vl.loadNamedStyle(u"C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\EingabeMesspunkt\\Messpunkte.qml",False)
vl.endEditCommand()
vl.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

The code to add a feature:

```
...
    fet = QgsFeature()
    fet.setGeometry(pt_z)
    fet.setFields(fields)              
    fet.setAttribute(0,idx)
    fet.setAttribute(1,PNR)
    if PointPhoto != "":
        fet.setAttribute(2,PointPhoto)
    fet.setAttribute(3,User)
    fet.setAttribute(4,strTime)
    fet.setAttribute(5,User)
    fet.setAttribute(6,strTime)
    fet.setAttribute(7,PointMethod)
    fet.setAttribute(8,PointMethod)

    layer.startEditing()
    layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([fet])
    layer.endEditCommand()
    layer.commitChanges()
```

...

Comment: For spatial Python problems please always include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Your question is in the reopening queue. It will be reopened after enough people agree it should be reopened. It depends on how quickly people get to it (opening and closing questions is done by volunteers, not paid moderators) but it seems like a clearcut case so it should be soon.

Comment: What happens if you disable snapping and re-enable it?

Comment: I tried this outside python, after adding a few features, which are pointfeatures. I thought, maybe new layers are not added automatically to the snapping environment. But there were no changes in the behavior. Also not snappable after reactivating snapping for all layers. First, I tried saving the project, also no effect.

Comment: When I copy the layer in qgis, I am able to snap the points in the copy. But it is no solution, to copy the layer, delete the original layer and rename the copy with python each time, when a feature is added, I think.